# Unable to debug Metadata version mismatch for module myapp/public/app/app.module.ts, found version 3, expected 4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Recently integrated angular material in my angular 4 app and right after I tried to compile the code, I am hit with this error :

> Metadata version mismatch for module myapp/public/app/app.module.ts,
>   found version 3, expected 4

Tried reverting back to my earlier package but still no luck. Any idea how to fix it up ?

Comment: I am also facing the exact same issue can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Was you uploaded your angular version to `5.0.0-rc.x`. If that, just update your `@angular/compiler-cli` to new version.